# Restrict access to url sent with Rails ActionMailer to recipient only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I've got a url I am sending users through ActionMailer. The person receiving the email is not a registered user. I want to restrict access to that certain url so only someone getting to it from the link in the mail can access it. 
Is there a known way to do that?

One thought i had was to add a token parameter to the url and validate against it when trying to open the link.

Any better ideas? Thanks!

Comment: to add a token parameter to the url and validate against it is the way i think